# Macola YYYYMMDD int- to SQL and Excel Date. This is too frustrating when it should be an easy fix.

Tags: sql, database, excel, date, converters

So, here's my issue. My company uses a Macola Database and we normally build reports in Crystal. That's not such an issue, as Macola was set up for Crystal If you need the formula to make that date work, it's really easy.

MacolaNumberToDate({Field_x}) 
If you're missing the dll, try reinstalling Macola, not just the dll.

My issue comes from all of our users that want to have their reports written in Excel, and the fact that Macola dates and Excel are at odds with each other.

Macola saves the date as int, so obviously it needs to be changed before Excel will recognize it as a date. The problem is that I haven't been able to find a single formula that will do this and not kick back an error. The format in Macola is YYYYMMDD, and it's saved as an int. What I finally figured out, after a great deal of searching, is that there are two issues with changing this to a date. One, integers can't just be changed to dates, and must go through more than one change before they allow dates.

There is a very helpful chart on this page for anyone else who is struggling with date conversions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

The second issue, is that when you go to change to a date from YYYYMMDD, sql has trouble parsing out how to lay out the numbers and hits an error. This is code that I came up with that works, but could probably use some clean up. I'm posting for all those like me who can't get it to do anything.

Cast((SUBSTRING(CAST(trx_dt AS char(8)),5,2) 
  + '/' 
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(trx_dt AS char(8)),7,2) 
  + '/' 
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(trx_dt AS char(8)),1,4)) as date)

I have one other issue now that I'd love to have help with. I need to use the above code in a case statement, and one of the WHEN statements needs to meet the criteria of the last day of last month based on trx_dt (but with the converter above or something better) and it needs to = the last day of last month. I need this dynamic, and the way I'm importing into Excel, I can't use variables.

Comment: @pnuts, today would be 20150113 (I come across it a lot with the data I have to use)

Answer (score 3):

two conversion methods, depending on where you want to do the conversion:

SQL-Server:

```
select cast(cast(trx_dt as char(8)) as date)
```

Excel:

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00"))
```

If you want the end of the current month, then there are functions that will give you that.
SQL-Server:

```
select DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, cast(cast(trx_dt as char(8)) as date)) + 1, 0))
```

Excel:

```
=EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00")),0)
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2012, SQL Server helpfully has an [EOMONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) built right in, too.